# Angular pwa swupdate not working until reinstall the app

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm having a hard time integrating angular's service worker into my application. I followed the guide and it works so far. I can create a shortcut on my home screen and launch into my app. The problem is that my app somehow doesn't update. If I change the name of a button, build the app and put it onto my server the app still shows the old version until uninstall and re-install the app.